# How to show that the intercept term, b0, can be expressed as a weighted sum of the dependent variables

Tags: regression, self-study

I came across this question as I was doing homework:

Show that the intercept term, b0, can be expressed as a weighted sum of the dependent variables. That is, show that $b_{0}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_{i,0}y_{i}$
Further, express the weights in terms of the slope weights, $w_{i}=\frac{x_{i}-\overline{x}}{s_{x}^{2}(n-1)}$

I have used the definition that $b_{0}=\overline{y}-b_{1}\overline{x}$

After some work, I get to this point $b_{0}=\overline{y}- \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_{i}-\overline{x})(y_{i}-\overline{y}) }{(x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}}\overline{x}$

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you find the coefficient of $y_1$ in the right hand side? This variable appears in $n+2$ out of the $2n+1$ shown terms: $\bar y$, $-y_1\bar{x}w_1$, and $\bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{x}w_i$ (which simplifies).

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). You've done what we like (+1) by showing us what you've done; we'll try to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @whuber I tried to collect the like terms and  find $y_{i}$'s coefficient, and I got the the following on numerator: $b_{0}=\overline{y} - \overline{x}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}y_{i}-\overline{x}y_{i}-\overline{x}\overline{y}+x_i \overline{y})$

Comment: Also, where does n+2 and 2n+1 come from... @whuber

Comment: $$\eqalign{b_0 &= \bar{y} - w_1(y_1-\bar y)\bar{x} - w_2(y_2-\bar y)\bar{x}  - \cdots - w_n(y_n-\bar y)\bar{x} \\ &= \bar{y} - w_1\bar{x}y_1 - \cdots - w_n\bar{x}y_n - w_1\bar{x}\bar{y} - \cdots - w_n\bar{x}\bar{y}}$$ has $1 + n + n = 2n+1$ terms.  Exactly $n+2$ of them include $y_1$ in them somewhere (because every occurrence of $\bar y$ includes $y_1$).

Comment: So, in the end, can we say it is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{i}{n}-w_i\overline{x})y_i$, where $\frac{i}{n}-w_i\overline{x}$ is the new $w_i$? @whuber